# React router takes an extra step to back to the last page

Tags: reactjs, react-router

I'm using react-router for routing my application. In my app, when I'm going to profile page (with username param) from home page (eg.01) and after that click the browser's back button, then I have to click twice to back to the home page. Because It takes a extra step to remove (?) from url. Could anyone help me to fix this.

I've used `this.transitionTo('profile', {username: username});` to navigate to  profile page 

eg.01:
`file:///E:/react-new/public/index.html#/` to `file:///E:/react-new/public/index.html?#/profile/iammerrick`